# How to remove multi-line with multi-pattern, awk pcre2grep sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, pcregrep

I have this text file

```
tittleofthis123
<Bunlde ver=5.0>
 <Packages>    
  <Package Type="app" FileName="Package_ARM64_beta.msix" Offset="79" Size="5791033">
   <Resources>
    rescode11
   </Resources>
   <b4:Dependencies>
     depcode12
   </b4:Dependencies>
  </Package>
  <Package Type="app" FileName="Package_x64_beta.msix" Offset="580113" Size="7195285">
   <Resources>
    rescode21
    rescode22
   </Resources>
  </Package>
  <Package Type="res" FileName="Package_lang-cy.msix" Offset="579" Size="15">
   <Resources>
    rescode31
   </Resources>
  </Package>
  <Package Type="res" FileName="Package_lang-af.msix" Offset="5791" Size="1578">
   <Resources>
    rescode41
   </Resources>
  </Package>
 </Packages>
</Bundle>
```

I need the output to be

```
tittleofthis123
<Bunlde ver=5.0>
 <Packages>    
  <Package Type="app" FileName="Package_x64_beta.msix" Offset="580113" Size="7195285">
   <Resources>
    rescode21
    rescode22
   </Resources>
  </Package>
  <Package Type="res" FileName="Package_lang-af.msix" Offset="5791" Size="1578">
   <Resources>
    rescode41
   </Resources>
  </Package>
 </Packages>
</Bundle>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep/2686705#2686705)

```
pcre2grep -M -v 'ARM64.*(\n|.)*</Package>|lang-cy.*(\n|.)*</Package>' 123.txt
```

But off course the result isn't right, because all the package have same `</Package>`, so instead filtering for ARM64 only, it filter out all to the bottom Package. And I have more Package to exclude, so probably I shouldn't use `-v` inverse, but no idea how to retain the `Title, <Bundle>, and <Packages>`

tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file/3718035#3718035) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318846/inverse-regex-in-awk/692794#692794)

```
awk '/ARM64/,/<\/Package>/ {next} {print}' 123.txt
```

It actually works well. But I don't understand how to make it filter more than one Package like `'/ARM64/,/<\/Package>/` and `/lang-cy/,/<\/Package>/`. And same, I need to exclude a lot of Package, so maybe not to do the `{next}` thing, still have no idea how to retain `Title, <Bundle>, and <Packages>`

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574090/manipulate-txt-searching-for-three-pattern-sed-awk-pcregrep/42574576#42574576) is pretty close to what I need

```
sed -n '/<Package/{:a;N;/\n*<\/Package>/!ba; /x64/p}' 123.txt
```

It also works very well, but my very incompetence still same, don't know how to join more filter like `x64` and`lang-af`. And same about the `Title, <Bundle>, and <Packages>`

Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725708/convert-pcregrep-command-in-awk-or-sed) is pretty much the same case, but I don't understand at the answer at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<Package Type/{:a;N;/<\/Package>/!ba;/_x64_\|_lang-af/!d}' file
```

Gather up lines between `<Package Type` and `</Package>` and do not delete the collection if it contains `_x64_` or `_lang-af`.

Comment: thank you so much @potong, I can't believe it, it works so well !

Answer (score 1):

> `awk '/ARM64/,/<\/Package>/ {next} {print}' 123.txt`
>
> It actually works well. But I don't understand how to make it filter
> more than one Package like `'/ARM64/,/<\/Package>/` and
> `/lang-cy/,/<\/Package>/`

As both ending condition are equal you might just use `||` (alternative) to build starting condition triggering both for `ARM64` and `lang-cy` following way

```
awk '/ARM64/||/lang-cy/,/<\/Package>/ {next} {print}' 123.txt
```

and use `||` again to get another exclusion for example to remove also `lang-af` you might do

```
awk '/ARM64/||/lang-cy/||/lang-af/,/<\/Package>/ {next} {print}' 123.txt
```

and so on.

**Warning**: what you have seems to be something akin to XML, be aware that GNU `AWK` is best suited for using with entities which could be described using regular expression. If your, could not be described by these, as is case with XML, then you would need tool for working with Chomsky Type-2 contraptions NOT regular expression in strictest sense.